# Getting NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults and adding elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I got button that allow user to mark post as favorite. 
This is my code :

```
+(NSMutableArray*) getFavoritePostsArray {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [userDefault mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favoritePostArray"];

    if ([tempArray count] == 0) {
        return [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        return tempArray;
    }
}
+(BOOL)addFavoritePost:(CostumSDPost *)post {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [GlobalFunctionAndVariable getFavoritePostsArray];
    NSDictionary *tempPost = @{
                               @"title" : post.title,
                               @"ID": post.ID,
                               @"imageURL": post.imageURl,
                               @"viewsNumber" : post.viewsNumber,
                               @"content" : post.content,
                               @"date": post.date,
                               @"authorName": post.authorName,
                               @"categoryList": post.categoryList,
                               @"commentsArra": post.commentsArray,
                               @"commentsStatus": post.commentsStatus,
                               @"commentsNumber":[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", post.commentsNumber],
                               };


    [tempArray addObject:tempPost];


    //[userDefault removeObjectForKey:@"favoritePostArray"];
    //[userDefault synchronize];
    [userDefault setObject:tempArray forKey:@"favoritePostArray"];
    //[userDefault synchronize];
    return YES;
}
```

This code work's only for first Time, when favoritePostArray is empty and the user add the first post to the array. 
Otherwise if I press another time the add Favorite Button to add others Post to favoritePostArray my app is blocked and no error is are shown.
I've used debug point and I figured that my app get blocked on this line

> [userDefault setObject:tempArray forKey:@"favoritePostArray"];

So what I missed here ?

Comment: Temp array has 3 objects previously added it's not null

Comment: BTW - Your `if` statement in `getFavoritePostsArray` should be `if (!tempArray)`. You only want to create a new array if `tempArray` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy it will not return nil array, but it will return empty array if it doesn't exist. Also for Those who voted down can I guess why what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: The first time your app runs, there won't be any data so it will return `nil` the first time.

Comment: Using this expression **NSMutableArray *tempArray = [userDefault mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favoritePostArray"];** will return an empty tempArray if it dosn't exist in NSUserDefaults. And with this expression **NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[userDefault arrayForKey:@"favoritePostArray"] mutableCopy];** it will return nil tempArray for first lunch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mutableArrayValueForKey` is a KVC method, not a method on NSUserDefaults.  Try this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[userDefault arrayForKey:@"favoritePostArray"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: That will only work on the upper level of the array. mutableCopy is a "shallow-mutable-copy" in reality. you'd also need to use "deep-mutable-copy". Luckily, on UserDefaults (which represents a .Plist style data structure, there is a CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy function in CoreFoundation to do the job. After this - you can freely use KVC on the array